# Kendo UI grid dependancies

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

In my app I only make use of kendo grids and consequently all the other modules that go with it such as dataSource etc.

My issue is that `kendo.all.min.js` is huge and takes a good second or two for clients' browsers to parse.

Where is a place that contains all the source files split out so I can pick and choose which modules I want in my app so I don't load everything, 90% of which my app doesn't use?

Answer (score 2):

The Kendo UI website has a custom builder where you can select only the modules you want:
http://www.telerik.com/download/custom-download

Comment: In order to use it I must have a licence though.

Comment: In order to use the Kendo UI Grid widget, you must have a license, unless you are using a version OLDER than 2014.1.416 and don't plan on upgrading. Telerik changed their licensing at that version and split into the free Kendo UI Core, and the paid Kendo UI Pro. The Pro version contains the more complicated widgets, including the Grid. http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/14-04-16/announcing-kendo-ui-core and a feature comparison table: http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/comparison

Answer (score 0):

You have a detailed list of dependencies on KendoUI site [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/javascript-dependencies) a specifically for `Grid` [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/javascript-dependencies#grid).

Keep in mind that the list might be shorter or longer depending on the features that you use (as editing, drag-and-drop, adaptive-rendering...)